# The next step after abstract submission in conferences

Tags: conference, paper-submission, springer

Well after the initial abstract  get accepted in conference, then the conference committee decide wether im going to talk ot submit poster.... Now the  question is i need to write a full paper since they said "special edition on conference papers will be published by springer".
If its not necessary  to provide full paper does the poster /abstract get published instead?

Comment: This is likely to vary from one conference to another. In the cases I've seen in computer science, abstracts are distributed at the conference, and this sometimes counts as publication, but a special edition published by Springer would include only selected papers (not mere abstracts, not posters). The way to find out how it works in your conference is to ask the organizers.

Comment: Well i ask however i got no response....

Comment: Well, if *they* don't know, how could *we* know? This varies greatly with the venue.

Comment: Im asking if anyone face such kind of situation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information can only be learned from the conference organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously only the conference organizers can answer this question definitively.  But typically, computer science conference proceedings only publish *papers*, not *abstracts* and not *posters*.  So if you want something to appear in the proceedings, you have to submit a paper.  Conversely, if you don’t submit a paper, your abstract won’t appear in the proceedings, so even if it’s distributed at the conference, it won’t count as a publication.

(On the other hand, you also typically have to submit a paper, not just an abstract, if you only want to give a talk/present a poster. So your statement “I have to write a paper” sounds really weird; don’t you already have a paper?)

The word “special” also suggests that the program committee will *invite* a subset of accepted authors to submit papers to the proceedings.  (For example: They might only publish papers that correspond to presentations, not posters.)  Sometimes these invitations are sent out before the conference, sometimes after.  (For example, they might ask for feedback from conference attendees on which presentations/posters to invite.) If you don’t have such an invitation (yet), submitting a paper may not even be an option (yet).

The “special edition” might also refer to a special issue of a *journal*. In that case, a small subset of presenters will be invited (typically *after* the conference) to submit *full archival* papers for publication, after the usual peer review process.

This should all be spelled out explicitly in the original call for submissions.

Comment: "Special" does not necessarily means that the PC will invite a subset of the papers. It can also be an open call _dedicated_ to the conference where other submissions, not limited to the conference presentations but close to the scope of it, are welcome.  In any case, all these should be explicitely written in the CfP. But I think I agree that the sentence points out to some LNCS proceedings (this is, probably, what "special" refers to)

Comment: @JeffE by "do i have to write a paper" im reffering to the fact that im already writing 3 others papers for journals plus im so lazy about adding another paper to my agenda. The corenfence doesnt clarify anything about publishing papers so i can understand wether it worth it adding another paper into my agenda or just withdraw and not attending....

Comment: @PsySp Good point.  Special issue protocols vary widely.